What is best package for convex optimization?
I have a set of problems of the form $\text{min} \|Ax-y\|_1$ with some constraints on the $x_i$.  A quick search turns up the cvxpy, scipy.optimize, and pyomo.environ packages. Which one of these has the best balance of terse definition of the problem and speed of execution?
I can do this in another platform but need it in Python. For example with
$A$
[[9.020656341904537, 9.05638588847761, 5.850654153832747, 7.825354360792511, 7.68054617392734],\
 [8.951287916930344, 8.348358334674362, 7.199349598864747, 9.715320144427697, 9.988683994212106],\
 [6.129161380647484, 9.231488085310017, 8.048848956776144, 6.855278438910625, 5.961441567122391]]

and $y$ =
[100, 100, 100]

and min and max bounds for the $x_i$ =
[[2.1055760036738236, 1.4816363955470813], \
 [2.3537948073947996, 1.600394673120251],  \
 [4.434106972916148, 2.35004064806864],    \
 [2.1779161331372263, 1.5170949985628575], \
 [4.048845780173668, 2.2372167006342556]]

I can get $x$ as
[2.1055758336242474, 2.3537948174586325, 4.434106958603555, 1.5393177230762531, 2.2372164252357996]

However, this was not done with Python.

The two other answers are great in themselves, but I thought it would be a good idea to compare the 3 solvers for the problem given in the question. So here we go:
Comparing Solvers for Convex Optimisation in Python
Problem Description
We compare SciPy, CVXPY, and Pyomo for solving a convex optimisation problem. The objective is to minimise the sum of absolute errors:
$$
\text{Minimise: } \sum_{i=1}^{n} |A_i x - y_i|
$$
subject to bounds on the decision variables:
$$
l_j \leq x_j \leq u_j, \; \forall j \in \{1, 2, \dots, m\}
$$
Python Implementation
The following code implements the problem using all three solvers and measures their performance:
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import cvxpy as cp
from pyomo.environ import ConcreteModel, Var, Objective, Constraint, NonNegativeReals, SolverFactory, minimize as pyomo_minimize
import time

# Data
A = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
])
y = np.array([10, 15, 20])
bounds = [
    (1.4816, 2.1056),
    (1.6004, 2.3538),
    (2.3500, 4.4341),
    (1.5171, 2.1779),
    (2.2372, 4.0488)
]

# SciPy Solver
start = time.time()
def objective_scipy(x):
    return np.sum(np.abs(A @ x - y))
x0 = np.mean(bounds, axis=1)
scipy_result = minimize(objective_scipy, x0, bounds=bounds, method='SLSQP')
scipy_time = time.time() - start
scipy_x = scipy_result.x

# CVXPY Solver
start = time.time()
x_cvxpy = cp.Variable(5)
objective_cvxpy = cp.Minimize(cp.norm1(A @ x_cvxpy - y))
constraints_cvxpy = [bounds[i][0] <= x_cvxpy[i] for i in range(5)] + [x_cvxpy[i] <= bounds[i][1] for i in range(5)]
problem_cvxpy = cp.Problem(objective_cvxpy, constraints_cvxpy)
problem_cvxpy.solve()
cvxpy_time = time.time() - start
cvxpy_x = x_cvxpy.value

# Pyomo Solver
start = time.time()
model = ConcreteModel()
model.x = Var(range(5), bounds=lambda model, i: bounds[i])
model.z = Var(range(3), domain=NonNegativeReals)
def objective_pyomo(model):
    return sum(model.z[i] for i in range(3))
model.objective = Objective(rule=objective_pyomo, sense=pyomo_minimize)
def abs_constraint_upper(model, i):
    return model.z[i] >= sum(A[i, j] * model.x[j] for j in range(5)) - y[i]
model.abs_upper = Constraint(range(3), rule=abs_constraint_upper)
def abs_constraint_lower(model, i):
    return model.z[i] >= -(sum(A[i, j] * model.x[j] for j in range(5)) - y[i])
model.abs_lower = Constraint(range(3), rule=abs_constraint_lower)
solver = SolverFactory('glpk')
solver.solve(model)
pyomo_time = time.time() - start
pyomo_x = [model.x[i].value for i in range(5)]

# Output Results
print(f"SciPy Optimal x: {scipy_x}, Time Taken: {scipy_time:.6f} seconds")
print(f"CVXPY Optimal x: {cvxpy_x}, Time Taken: {cvxpy_time:.6f} seconds")
print(f"Pyomo Optimal x: {pyomo_x}, Time Taken: {pyomo_time:.6f} seconds")

Results
Solver  Optimal $x$ Time Taken (s)
SciPy   [1.4816, 1.6004, 2.35, 1.5171, 2.2372]  0.000791
CVXPY   [1.4816, 1.60039999, 2.34999997, 1.51709999, 2.23719998]    0.007145
Pyomo   [1.4816, 1.6004, 2.35, 1.5171, 2.2372]  0.008568

Analysis

SciPy is the fastest, making it ideal for small, simple problems with smooth objectives.
CVXPY is slower due to problem reformulation but supports complex convex optimisation problems with advanced constraints.
Pyomo is the slowest, owing to its focus on flexibility and large-scale model customisation.

Recommendations

Use SciPy for small-scale optimisation where speed is crucial. Why:

Speed: SciPy was the fastest among the solvers, with a runtime of 0.000791 seconds. This is due to its lightweight design and efficient implementation of algorithms like SLSQP.
Simplicity: Its API is straightforward for smooth optimisation problems, making it suitable for cases with basic constraints and objectives.
Limitations: It lacks built-in support for handling non-smooth objectives, complex constraints, or large-scale problems.


Opt for CVXPY for more complex convex models or when flexibility in solver choice is needed. Why:

Flexibility: CVXPY reformulates problems into a canonical convex optimisation form, allowing users to handle advanced features such as non-smooth objectives, general convex constraints, and custom solvers.
Solver Choice: It supports multiple solvers (eg., OSQP, SCS, and ECOS), providing flexibility for different problem types.
Performance Trade-Off: Although slower (0.007145 seconds), its generality makes it ideal for complex convex problems. The slight delay is acceptable given its versatility.
Limitations: Overhead in problem reformulation makes it slower for simpler tasks, and it lacks direct support for non-convex or mixed-integer programming.


Choose Pyomo for large-scale problems, mixed-integer optimisation, or structured modelling requirements. Why:

Modelling Power: Pyomo excels in algebraic modelling, supporting linear, non-linear, and mixed-integer optimisation.
Scalability: Its structured approach makes it better suited for large-scale industrial applications and complex models.
Solver Integration: Pyomo integrates with solvers like GLPK, CBC, and IPOPT, making it robust for a wide range of problem types.
Limitations: It was the slowest (0.008568 seconds), with significant overhead due to its focus on modularity and extensibility.



Decision Criteria for Recommendations
| Criteria          | SciPy                  | CVXPY                 | Pyomo                     |
|--------------------|------------------------|------------------------|---------------------------|
| **Speed**         | Fastest                | Moderate               | Slowest                   |
| **Complexity**    | Handles simple cases   | Handles convex cases   | Handles complex models    |
| **Flexibility**   | Limited                | Moderate               | High                      |
| **Scalability**   | Limited                | Moderate               | High                      |


Many thanks for this very comprehensive answer. +1

You’re very welcome @Edmund , I hope it is useful to you .

Scipy's minimize might be what you're looking for. It has a good variety of solvers and accepts bounds/constraints.
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np

def f(x, *args):
    return ((A @ x - b)**2.).mean()

A = np.array([[9.020656341904537, 9.05638588847761, 5.850654153832747, 7.825354360792511, 7.68054617392734],
              [8.951287916930344, 8.348358334674362, 7.199349598864747, 9.715320144427697, 9.988683994212106],
              [6.129161380647484, 9.231488085310017, 8.048848956776144, 6.855278438910625, 5.961441567122391]])

b = np.array([100, 100, 100])

# Edmund's solution.
ed_sol = np.array([2.1055758336242474, 2.3537948174586325, 4.434106958603555, 1.5393177230762531, 2.2372164252357996])

bounds = np.array([[2.1055760036738236, 1.4816363955470813],
                   [2.3537948073947996, 1.600394673120251],
                   [4.434106972916148, 2.35004064806864],    
                   [2.1779161331372263, 1.5170949985628575], 
                   [4.048845780173668, 2.2372167006342556]])
bounds = bounds.T[[1,0]].T

# Scipy's solution.
sp_sol = minimize(f, np.zeros((5,), dtype=np.float64), bounds=bounds)

print(f"Edmund's solution: {ed_sol}")
print(f"Scipy's solution: {sp_sol.x}")


Thanks for this example with scipy.optimize.  The results are practically identical and perhaps only difference in working precision of the implementation. +1

In my experience, CVXPY is the best for convex optimization, in Python.
CVXPY can select several state-of-the-art solvers, such as OSCP, SCS, and so on.
In fact, Gurobi is the fastest and most accurate solver I have ever used, but you have to pay money for it, and if you are a university student, you might be able to get a trail access.

I have looked at some AI generated coding using CVXPY and it reads more like math than scipy.optimize so I am leaning towards selecting CVXPY. +1
